# syntax error near unexpected token in jupyter terminal

Tags: r, shell, jupyter

I write a r script below and want to run it in jupyter terminal. But it shows error:

./Rda_to_csv.r: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('

./Rda_to_csv.r: line 1: `folders <- list.files('TE_uncompressed/')'

I wonder why this happens and how to fix it? thanks!

```
folders <- list.files('TE_uncompressed/')
for(folder in folders)
  {
  files <- list.files(folder)
  files <- files[grepl(".rda", files, ignore.case=TRUE)]
  for(file in files){
    path_n_name <- paste0(folder, "/", file)
    raw_read <- load(path_n_name)
    out_path_n_name <- gsub(".rda", ".csv", path_n_name, ignore.case = T)
    write.csv(df_out, out_path_n_name,fileEncoding="UTF-8")
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't (currently) run jupyter, but perhaps try to move the open-brace on the same line as `for` instead of on the next line. I know this generally works in R, I wonder if jupyter is doing anything differently in the parsing? (just a guess)

Comment: @ r2evans Thanks for response.
But I think it's not that error as it also shows incorrect.

Comment: Okay. It's interesting to me that the error is showing double-quotes but your code is using single quotes. Do we have the correct code in the question, or have you made updates to the error and didn't update the code?

Comment: @r2evans Oh, I do not update the error. The situation is that when I use double-quotes in r script, the error will show double-quotes error. When I use single quote in r script, the error will show single quote error.